# How can I create a non-static inner Activity class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm going to create a `Fragment` that have an `Activity` to managing that fragment; Like this:

```
public class Form extends Fragment {
    // TODO some code ...

    public class Dialog extends FragmentActivity {
        // TODO some code ..
    }
}
```

but it show me error, So I crated it with a `static` inner `Activity` but an static inner class don't get me that accesses.

Comment: yes; in fact main part of  that fragment is a button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to make this work. Android requires Activities to have a public no-arg constructor. Non-static inner classes can't be created without an instance of the outer class, and the Android framework doesn't have (and very much shouldn't have) a way to instantiate a Fragment for the purposes of instantiating an Activity.

Comment: so are there any way for managing that Fragment (Form) by that Activity (Dialog)?

Comment: Make `Form` a separated class, then initiate it in `Dialog`, something like `setForm`